# KM survival time transfer function in Cox reg

Tags: cox-model, time-varying-covariate

I have a binary risk factor that can change value over time.  I corrected the data using `tmerge()`.  It turns out that the risk factor loses its effect over time.  So, introduced an identity time transfer into the `coxph()`.  I have two questions: 1) How can I use the K-M time transfer function in the call to `coxph()` instead?  2) Once I introduced the tt function into `coxph()`, the resulting object had many more residuals (and linear predictor values) than I had in the original data after `tmerge()`.  Here is an example to illustrate.

```
library(asaur)
library(dplyr)
library(survival)
panc <- asaur::pancreatic2 %>% 
   mutate(stage.n = as.numeric(stage == "M"))
result <- coxph(Surv(pfs) ~ stage.n,data=panc)
length(residuals(result,type = 'deviance'))   # 41 
temp <- cox.zph(result.coxph,transform="km") # check PH assumption
print(temp)
         rho chisq      p
stageM -0.328  3.86 0.0496
plot(temp[1],main='transform=K-M(time)',xlab='K-M(time)') # effect diminishes over time
```

How would you change the code to use K-M survival time transfer instead?

```
result.tt <- update(result.coxph, .~. + tt(stage.n), 
                    tt = function(x, t, ...) x * t)
```

Why 741 residuals when there are only 41 subjects?

```
length(residuals(result.tt,type = 'deviance'))  
    [1] 741
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using a K-M based scaling of time to model a time-dependent coefficient for `stage.n`?

Comment: First, thank you for excellent reply. I wanted a good fit to the decay of beta as a function of time for my own data (panc is for illustration).    Since cox.zph() offers 4 alternatives, I wanted to see if there was a simple way to implement those like km or rank, just using a text argument or something to that effect.  Sounds like there isn’t other getting from another function, and further, you don’t recommend k-m as not being especially sensible.    For selecting tt, I used plot(temp) and added curves from fitting alternatives.  Compared LRT stats w/ same df. Anything else recommended?

Comment: As the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) on time-dependent covariates says (page 17): "The cox.zph plot is excellent for diagnosis but does not, however, produce a formal fit..." Looking at the apparent coefficient as a function of untransformed time (`transform="identity"`) in the cox.zph plot may suggest a general form for the time dependence that you could include in your `tt()` function. A log-based time transform is shown in the vignette. Also, note that `cox.zph()` uses Schoenfeld residuals, not the deviance residuals of your example.

Comment: thanks for direction. Point noted about the type of residuals used in diagnostics of PH assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reverse order:

2) When you estimate a time-dependent coefficient by using `tt()`, there is no longer a single covariate value associated with each patient. The covariate values need to be determined for all cases still at risk at each event time, taking the time-dependence function into account. This increases the number of observations from 1 per patient to the sum of all patients still at risk over all event times.

In your example all cases have events. So when the first event happens you need to determine all 41 covariate values; at the second event, there are 40 to calculate, and so on. This could in principle give you up to 861 covariate values, but there are 4 ties in survival times in this data set decreasing the total number of observations.

To see the underlying data structures that are generated to do the Cox regression, examine the $x$ and $y$ values in your Cox model, for example:

```
result.3 <- coxph(Surv(pfs) ~ stage.n + tt(stage.n),tt=function(x, t, ...) x * t,data=panc,x=TRUE,y=TRUE)
xyCox <- cbind(result.3$x,result.3$y)
dim(xyCox)
[1] 741   4
```

and note that several observations are now associated with each patient up to that patient's event time, shown here for patient 1:

```
xyCox[grepl("^1\\.|^1$",rownames(xyCox)),]
    stage.n tt(stage.n) time status
1         1          48   48      1
1.1       1          43   43      0
1.2       1          42   42      0
1.3       1          36   36      0
```

Deviance residuals are calculated for each observation, not just for each event, so you end up with 741 residuals calculated.

1) In principle, you can use any function involving time in the `tt()` formalism. So if you want to use a K-M survival estimate as the function of time, you just have to write a function that returns the K-M estimate for each time. If you type `cox.zph` at the R prompt when its `survival` package is loaded, you can see how that function accomplishes this task; it calls `survfitKM()` on a null model of the survival data at hand. Note that with a null model the K-M estimate is strictly empirical without taking covariates into account.

It's not clear, however, that using this type of K-M estimate in a time-dependence function would make much sense. For this approach to be a reasonable model of reality, the processes in an individual leading to an event would somehow have to know the survival data for all members of the cohort that provide the empirical K-M estimate. It would seem to make more sense to define some reasonable continuous function of time that depends only on the particular individual at risk.